# Synchronization of Events

Tags: design-patterns, synchronization, event-driven

I have some procceses using event-driven architecture that sends a random number of events at the beginning of the processing. Althout, in a certain point of the business I need to check if all of those events ended their processing.
Considering that I need to keep the idenpotency of each step of the processing, is there a design pattern that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like Mediator pattern to me, where the processes do not communicate to each other to check if all the events ended their processing. They communicate to a mediator which may inform them back when all the events complete.

Comment: As your own question suggests, you might want to look at the Process Manager pattern.